# R Shiny CSS: Remove space between specific rows while leaving all other spacing intact

Tags: css, r, user-interface, shiny

I have an R Shiny application with four rows. The first and third row consist of selectInput dropdowns, whereas the second and fourth rows consist of text output.

The application looks like this:

[image]

I would like to eliminate the space (margin-bottom) between the first and second row while keeping all other distances in the application the same. To be clear, this means the space between the third and fourth rows should still exist after the solution.

Here is the code to render the application:

```
ui <- shiny::navbarPage(

shiny::tabPanel(title = "My Tab",
                value = "my-tab",
              
              #-----PANEL-----
              
              shinyjs::inlineCSS("#panel1.ap { padding-top: 10px; padding-left: 30px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-right: 0px; background-color: #cccccc; border-style: solid; border-color: black; border-width: 1px; }"),

              shiny::absolutePanel(id = "panel1",
                                   class = "ap",
                                   fixed = TRUE,
                                   draggable = FALSE,
                                   top = 366,
                                   left = 55,
                                   right = "auto",
                                   bottom = "auto",
                                   width = 1074,
                                   height = 220,
                                   
                                   shinyjs::inlineCSS("button.btn.radiobtn.btn-default.active { background-color: white; }"),

                                   shiny::fluidRow(
                                                   shiny::column(width = 2,
                                                                 shiny::selectInput(inputId = "c1",
                                                                                    label = "Condition 1",
                                                                                    choices = c("Bad","Fair","Good"),
                                                                                    selected = "Fair",
                                                                                    width = "130px"),
                                                   ),
                                                   shiny::column(width = 2,
                                                                 shiny::selectInput(inputId = "c2",
                                                                                    label = "Condition 2",
                                                                                    choices = c("Bad","Fair","Good"),
                                                                                    selected = "Good",
                                                                                    width = "130px"),
                                                   ),
                                                   shiny::column(width = 2,
                                                                 shiny::selectInput(inputId = "c3",
                                                                                    label = "Condition 3",
                                                                                    choices = c("Bad","Fair","Good"),
                                                                                    selected = "Good",
                                                                                    width = "130px"),
                                                   ),
                                                   shiny::column(width = 2,
                                                                 shiny::selectInput(inputId = "c4",
                                                                                    label = "Condition 4",
                                                                                    choices = c("Bad","Fair","Good"),
                                                                                    selected = "Good",
                                                                                    width = "130px"),
                                                   ),
                                                   shiny::column(width = 2,
                                                                 shiny::selectInput(inputId = "c5",
                                                                                    label = "Condition 5",
                                                                                    choices = c("Bad","Fair","Good"),
                                                                                    selected = "Good",
                                                                                    width = "130px"),
                                                   ),
                                                   shiny::column(width = 2,
                                                                 shiny::selectInput(inputId = "c6",
                                                                                    label = "Condition 6",
                                                                                    choices = c("Bad","Fair","Good"),
                                                                                    selected = "Good",
                                                                                    width = "130px")
                                                   )
                                   ),
                                   
                                   shiny::fluidRow(
                                     shiny::column(width = 2,
                                                   htmltools::p(id = "condition-words-1", "Condition words 1")),
                                     shiny::column(width = 2,
                                                   htmltools::p(id = "condition-words-2", "Condition words 2")),
                                     shiny::column(width = 2,
                                                   htmltools::p(id = "condition-words-3", "Condition words 3")),
                                     shiny::column(width = 2,
                                                   htmltools::p(id = "condition-words-4", "Condition words 4")),
                                     shiny::column(width = 2,
                                                   htmltools::p(id = "condition-words-5", "Condition words 5")),
                                     shiny::column(width = 2,
                                                   htmltools::p(id = "condition-words-6", "Condition words 6"))
                                   ),
                                   
                                   shiny::fluidRow(
                                     shiny::column(width = 2,
                                                   shiny::selectInput(inputId = "i1",
                                                                      label = "Item 1",
                                                                      choices = c("Bad","Fair","Good"),
                                                                      selected = "Fair",
                                                                      width = "130px"),
                                     ),
                                     shiny::column(width = 2,
                                                   shiny::selectInput(inputId = "i2",
                                                                      label = "Item 2",
                                                                      choices = c("Bad","Fair","Good"),
                                                                      selected = "Good",
                                                                      width = "130px"),
                                     ),
                                     shiny::column(width = 2,
                                                   shiny::selectInput(inputId = "i3",
                                                                      label = "Item 3",
                                                                      choices = c("Bad","Fair","Good"),
                                                                      selected = "Good",
                                                                      width = "130px"),
                                     ),
                                     shiny::column(width = 2,
                                                   shiny::selectInput(inputId = "i4",
                                                                      label = "Item 4",
                                                                      choices = c("Bad","Fair","Good"),
                                                                      selected = "Good",
                                                                      width = "130px"),
                                     ),
                                     shiny::column(width = 2,
                                                   shiny::selectInput(inputId = "i5",
                                                                      label = "Item 5",
                                                                      choices = c("Bad","Fair","Good"),
                                                                      selected = "Good",
                                                                      width = "130px"),
                                     ),
                                     shiny::column(width = 2,
                                                   shiny::selectInput(inputId = "i6",
                                                                      label = "Item 6",
                                                                      choices = c("Bad","Fair","Good"),
                                                                      selected = "Good",
                                                                      width = "130px")
                                     )
                                   ), 
                                   
                                   shiny::fluidRow(
                                     shiny::column(width = 2,
                                                   htmltools::p(id = "item-words-1", "Item words 1")),
                                     shiny::column(width = 2,
                                                   htmltools::p(id = "item-words-2", "Item words 2")),
                                     shiny::column(width = 2,
                                                   htmltools::p(id = "item-words-3", "Item words 3")),
                                     shiny::column(width = 2,
                                                   htmltools::p(id = "item-words-4", "Item words 4")),
                                     shiny::column(width = 2,
                                                   htmltools::p(id = "item-words-5", "Item words 5")),
                                     shiny::column(width = 2,
                                                   htmltools::p(id = "item-words-6", "Item words 6"))
                                   )
                                   
              ) # ** End absolute panel ** #
              
) # ** End Tab ** #

) # ** End UI function ** #

server <- function(input, output, session) { }


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I have used the google chrome inspect tool to try to implement CSS to solve this issue, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Your assistance will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right track - margin-bottom / margin-top does what you want:

```
ui <- shiny::navbarPage(
  
  shiny::tabPanel(title = "My Tab",
                  value = "my-tab",
                  
                  #-----PANEL-----
                  
                  shinyjs::inlineCSS("#panel1.ap { padding-top: 10px; padding-left: 30px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-right: 0px; background-color: #cccccc; border-style: solid; border-color: black; border-width: 1px; }"),
                  
                  shiny::absolutePanel(id = "panel1",
                                       class = "ap",
                                       fixed = TRUE,
                                       draggable = FALSE,
                                       top = 366,
                                       left = 55,
                                       right = "auto",
                                       bottom = "auto",
                                       width = 1074,
                                       height = 220,
                                       
                                       shinyjs::inlineCSS("button.btn.radiobtn.btn-default.active { background-color: white; }"),
                                       
                                       shiny::fluidRow(
                                         shiny::column(width = 2,
                                                       shiny::selectInput(inputId = "c1",
                                                                          label = "Condition 1",
                                                                          choices = c("Bad","Fair","Good"),
                                                                          selected = "Fair",
                                                                          width = "130px"),
                                                       style = "margin-bottom:-15px;"
                                         ),
                                         shiny::column(width = 2,
                                                       shiny::selectInput(inputId = "c2",
                                                                          label = "Condition 2",
                                                                          choices = c("Bad","Fair","Good"),
                                                                          selected = "Good",
                                                                          width = "130px"),
                                                       style = "margin-bottom:-15px;"
                                         ),
                                         shiny::column(width = 2,
                                                       shiny::selectInput(inputId = "c3",
                                                                          label = "Condition 3",
                                                                          choices = c("Bad","Fair","Good"),
                                                                          selected = "Good",
                                                                          width = "130px"),
                                                       style = "margin-bottom:-15px;"
                                         ),
                                         shiny::column(width = 2,
                                                       shiny::selectInput(inputId = "c4",
                                                                          label = "Condition 4",
                                                                          choices = c("Bad","Fair","Good"),
                                                                          selected = "Good",
                                                                          width = "130px"),
                                                       style = "margin-bottom:-15px;"
                                         ),
                                         shiny::column(width = 2,
                                                       shiny::selectInput(inputId = "c5",
                                                                          label = "Condition 5",
                                                                          choices = c("Bad","Fair","Good"),
                                                                          selected = "Good",
                                                                          width = "130px"),
                                                       style = "margin-bottom:-15px;"
                                         ),
                                         shiny::column(width = 2,
                                                       shiny::selectInput(inputId = "c6",
                                                                          label = "Condition 6",
                                                                          choices = c("Bad","Fair","Good"),
                                                                          selected = "Good",
                                                                          width = "130px"),
                                                       style = "margin-bottom:-15px;"
                                         )
                                       ),
                                       
                                       shiny::fluidRow(
                                         shiny::column(width = 2,
                                                       htmltools::p(id = "condition-words-1", "Condition words 1")),
                                         shiny::column(width = 2,
                                                       htmltools::p(id = "condition-words-2", "Condition words 2")),
                                         shiny::column(width = 2,
                                                       htmltools::p(id = "condition-words-3", "Condition words 3")),
                                         shiny::column(width = 2,
                                                       htmltools::p(id = "condition-words-4", "Condition words 4")),
                                         shiny::column(width = 2,
                                                       htmltools::p(id = "condition-words-5", "Condition words 5")),
                                         shiny::column(width = 2,
                                                       htmltools::p(id = "condition-words-6", "Condition words 6"))
                                       ),
                                       
                                       shiny::fluidRow(
                                         shiny::column(width = 2,
                                                       shiny::selectInput(inputId = "i1",
                                                                          label = "Item 1",
                                                                          choices = c("Bad","Fair","Good"),
                                                                          selected = "Fair",
                                                                          width = "130px"),
                                         ),
                                         shiny::column(width = 2,
                                                       shiny::selectInput(inputId = "i2",
                                                                          label = "Item 2",
                                                                          choices = c("Bad","Fair","Good"),
                                                                          selected = "Good",
                                                                          width = "130px"),
                                         ),
                                         shiny::column(width = 2,
                                                       shiny::selectInput(inputId = "i3",
                                                                          label = "Item 3",
                                                                          choices = c("Bad","Fair","Good"),
                                                                          selected = "Good",
                                                                          width = "130px"),
                                         ),
                                         shiny::column(width = 2,
                                                       shiny::selectInput(inputId = "i4",
                                                                          label = "Item 4",
                                                                          choices = c("Bad","Fair","Good"),
                                                                          selected = "Good",
                                                                          width = "130px"),
                                         ),
                                         shiny::column(width = 2,
                                                       shiny::selectInput(inputId = "i5",
                                                                          label = "Item 5",
                                                                          choices = c("Bad","Fair","Good"),
                                                                          selected = "Good",
                                                                          width = "130px"),
                                         ),
                                         shiny::column(width = 2,
                                                       shiny::selectInput(inputId = "i6",
                                                                          label = "Item 6",
                                                                          choices = c("Bad","Fair","Good"),
                                                                          selected = "Good",
                                                                          width = "130px")
                                         )
                                       ), 
                                       
                                       shiny::fluidRow(
                                         shiny::column(width = 2,
                                                       htmltools::p(id = "item-words-1", "Item words 1")),
                                         shiny::column(width = 2,
                                                       htmltools::p(id = "item-words-2", "Item words 2")),
                                         shiny::column(width = 2,
                                                       htmltools::p(id = "item-words-3", "Item words 3")),
                                         shiny::column(width = 2,
                                                       htmltools::p(id = "item-words-4", "Item words 4")),
                                         shiny::column(width = 2,
                                                       htmltools::p(id = "item-words-5", "Item words 5")),
                                         shiny::column(width = 2,
                                                       htmltools::p(id = "item-words-6", "Item words 6"))
                                       )
                                       
                  ) # ** End absolute panel ** #
                  
  ) # ** End Tab ** #
  
) # ** End UI function ** #

server <- function(input, output, session) { }


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

Using `margin-top`:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shiny::navbarPage(
  
  shiny::tabPanel(title = "My Tab",
                  value = "my-tab",
                  
                  #-----PANEL-----
                  
                  shinyjs::inlineCSS("#panel1.ap { padding-top: 10px; padding-left: 30px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-right: 0px; background-color: #cccccc; border-style: solid; border-color: black; border-width: 1px; }"),
                  
                  shiny::absolutePanel(id = "panel1",
                                       class = "ap",
                                       fixed = TRUE,
                                       draggable = FALSE,
                                       top = 366,
                                       left = 55,
                                       right = "auto",
                                       bottom = "auto",
                                       width = 1074,
                                       height = 220,
                                       
                                       shinyjs::inlineCSS("button.btn.radiobtn.btn-default.active { background-color: white; }"),
                                       
                                       shiny::fluidRow(
                                         shiny::column(width = 2,
                                                       shiny::selectInput(inputId = "c1",
                                                                          label = "Condition 1",
                                                                          choices = c("Bad","Fair","Good"),
                                                                          selected = "Fair",
                                                                          width = "130px"),
                                         ),
                                         shiny::column(width = 2,
                                                       shiny::selectInput(inputId = "c2",
                                                                          label = "Condition 2",
                                                                          choices = c("Bad","Fair","Good"),
                                                                          selected = "Good",
                                                                          width = "130px"),
                                         ),
                                         shiny::column(width = 2,
                                                       shiny::selectInput(inputId = "c3",
                                                                          label = "Condition 3",
                                                                          choices = c("Bad","Fair","Good"),
                                                                          selected = "Good",
                                                                          width = "130px"),
                                         ),
                                         shiny::column(width = 2,
                                                       shiny::selectInput(inputId = "c4",
                                                                          label = "Condition 4",
                                                                          choices = c("Bad","Fair","Good"),
                                                                          selected = "Good",
                                                                          width = "130px"),
                                         ),
                                         shiny::column(width = 2,
                                                       shiny::selectInput(inputId = "c5",
                                                                          label = "Condition 5",
                                                                          choices = c("Bad","Fair","Good"),
                                                                          selected = "Good",
                                                                          width = "130px"),
                                         ),
                                         shiny::column(width = 2,
                                                       shiny::selectInput(inputId = "c6",
                                                                          label = "Condition 6",
                                                                          choices = c("Bad","Fair","Good"),
                                                                          selected = "Good",
                                                                          width = "130px")
                                         )
                                       ),
                                       
                                       shiny::fluidRow(
                                         shiny::column(width = 2,
                                                       htmltools::p(id = "condition-words-1", "Condition words 1"),
                                                       style = "margin-top:-15px;"),
                                         shiny::column(width = 2,
                                                       htmltools::p(id = "condition-words-2", "Condition words 2"),
                                                       style = "margin-top:-15px;"),
                                         shiny::column(width = 2,
                                                       htmltools::p(id = "condition-words-3", "Condition words 3"),
                                                       style = "margin-top:-15px;"),
                                         shiny::column(width = 2,
                                                       htmltools::p(id = "condition-words-4", "Condition words 4"),
                                                       style = "margin-top:-15px;"),
                                         shiny::column(width = 2,
                                                       htmltools::p(id = "condition-words-5", "Condition words 5"),
                                                       style = "margin-top:-15px;"),
                                         shiny::column(width = 2,
                                                       htmltools::p(id = "condition-words-6", "Condition words 6"),
                                                       style = "margin-top:-15px;")
                                       ),
                                       
                                       shiny::fluidRow(
                                         shiny::column(width = 2,
                                                       shiny::selectInput(inputId = "i1",
                                                                          label = "Item 1",
                                                                          choices = c("Bad","Fair","Good"),
                                                                          selected = "Fair",
                                                                          width = "130px"),
                                         ),
                                         shiny::column(width = 2,
                                                       shiny::selectInput(inputId = "i2",
                                                                          label = "Item 2",
                                                                          choices = c("Bad","Fair","Good"),
                                                                          selected = "Good",
                                                                          width = "130px"),
                                         ),
                                         shiny::column(width = 2,
                                                       shiny::selectInput(inputId = "i3",
                                                                          label = "Item 3",
                                                                          choices = c("Bad","Fair","Good"),
                                                                          selected = "Good",
                                                                          width = "130px"),
                                         ),
                                         shiny::column(width = 2,
                                                       shiny::selectInput(inputId = "i4",
                                                                          label = "Item 4",
                                                                          choices = c("Bad","Fair","Good"),
                                                                          selected = "Good",
                                                                          width = "130px"),
                                         ),
                                         shiny::column(width = 2,
                                                       shiny::selectInput(inputId = "i5",
                                                                          label = "Item 5",
                                                                          choices = c("Bad","Fair","Good"),
                                                                          selected = "Good",
                                                                          width = "130px"),
                                         ),
                                         shiny::column(width = 2,
                                                       shiny::selectInput(inputId = "i6",
                                                                          label = "Item 6",
                                                                          choices = c("Bad","Fair","Good"),
                                                                          selected = "Good",
                                                                          width = "130px")
                                         )
                                       ), 
                                       
                                       shiny::fluidRow(
                                         shiny::column(width = 2,
                                                       htmltools::p(id = "item-words-1", "Item words 1")),
                                         shiny::column(width = 2,
                                                       htmltools::p(id = "item-words-2", "Item words 2")),
                                         shiny::column(width = 2,
                                                       htmltools::p(id = "item-words-3", "Item words 3")),
                                         shiny::column(width = 2,
                                                       htmltools::p(id = "item-words-4", "Item words 4")),
                                         shiny::column(width = 2,
                                                       htmltools::p(id = "item-words-5", "Item words 5")),
                                         shiny::column(width = 2,
                                                       htmltools::p(id = "item-words-6", "Item words 6"))
                                       )
                                       
                  ) # ** End absolute panel ** #
                  
  ) # ** End Tab ** #
  
) # ** End UI function ** #

server <- function(input, output, session) { }


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Excellent job! I kept trying style="margin-bottom: 0px;". I didn't realize I needed to go with style="margin-bottom: -15px;". Thanks for the quick assistance.