# Align Inputs with Labels and ActionButton vertically in fluidRow

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

In my `shinydashboardPlus` app, I use `fluidRow`/`column` to specify my layout. Sometimes, I have one or several `textInput` / `selectInput` and an `actionButton` in one row. Since the input elements do have a label, they are vertically larger than the button, which does not look very nice. For example:

[image: vertically unaligned]

Is there an easy way to move the `actionButton` a little below so that it is in line with, for example, the "local" element?

Here is a minimal example:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)

ui <- shinydashboardPlus::dashboardPage(
    header=shinydashboardPlus::dashboardHeader(title = "Align Example"),
    sidebar=shinydashboardPlus::dashboardSidebar(
        shinydashboard::sidebarMenu(id = "tabs",
            shinydashboard::menuItem(
                "Welcome", tabName = "welcome"
            )
        )
    ),
    body=shinydashboard::dashboardBody(
        shinydashboard::tabItems(
            shinydashboard::tabItem(tabName="welcome", 
                shiny::fluidRow(
                    shinydashboardPlus::box(
                        status="black", solidHeader = TRUE, width=12, closable = FALSE,
                        title="Welcome!",
                        shiny::column(4, 
                            shiny::textInput("username", label="User Name:")
                        ),
                        shiny::column(4, 
                            shiny::passwordInput("passwd", label="Password:")
                        ),
                        shiny::column(2, 
                            shiny::selectInput(inputId="dbmode", "Modus:",
                                choices = c("production", "test", "local"),
                                selected = "local"
                            )
                        ),
                        shiny::column(2, 
                            shiny::actionButton("dbconnect", "Connect!")
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )   
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
}

shiny::shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went for an alternative approach:

I looked at how shiny creates labels for other form components in the same row. Shiny adds a `div` container with a `label` similar to the one provided in the code below. By using the same classes shiny uses, I get the right dimensions without specifying pixels or distances manually.

```
column(
        width = 2,
        div(
          class="form-group shiny-input-container",
          shiny::tags$label("\u00a0", class="control-label"),
          div(actionButton("dbconnect", "Connect!"))
        )
      )
```

Answer (score 2):

With the help of SelectorGadget and then searching SO for "margin-bottom", I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69259443/216064), which led me to

```
shiny::column(2, 
    shiny::actionButton(ns("dbconnect"), "Connect!"),
    style = "margin-top:25px;" ## <-- !
)
```

Not sure if this is good practice, but I am happy for now.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I can think of is to ad a `br()` before the action button:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)

ui <- shinydashboardPlus::dashboardPage(
  header=shinydashboardPlus::dashboardHeader(title = "Align Example"),
  sidebar=shinydashboardPlus::dashboardSidebar(
    shinydashboard::sidebarMenu(id = "tabs",
                                shinydashboard::menuItem(
                                  "Welcome", tabName = "welcome"
                                )
    )
  ),
  body=shinydashboard::dashboardBody(
    shinydashboard::tabItems(
      shinydashboard::tabItem(tabName="welcome", 
                              shiny::fluidRow(
                                shinydashboardPlus::box(
                                  status="black", solidHeader = TRUE, width=12, closable = FALSE,
                                  title="Welcome!",
                                  shiny::column(4, 
                                                shiny::textInput("username", label="User Name:")
                                  ),
                                  shiny::column(4, 
                                                shiny::passwordInput("passwd", label="Password:")
                                  ),
                                  shiny::column(2, 
                                                shiny::selectInput(inputId="dbmode", "Modus:",
                                                                   choices = c("production", "test", "local"),
                                                                   selected = "local"
                                                )
                                  ),
                                  shiny::column(2,
                                                br(),
                                                shiny::actionButton("dbconnect", "Connect!")
                                  )
                                )
                              )
      )
    )   
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
}

shiny::shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: That's good already, but a few pixels more would be nice. Using SelectorGadget, I see that there seems to be a margin-bottom:5px involved. I try to figure out how to add that..